# angular with requirejs - Argument controller is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I'm trying to use angular with requirejs. Here is my `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script data-main="/js/app.js" src="/bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
    <div ng-view ng-controller="accountController"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js file

```
require.config (
            {
            appDir  : '',
            baseUrl : '/js/',
            paths   :
            {
                // Configure alias to full paths
                'angular': '/bower_components/angular/angular.min',
                'ngRoute': '/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min',
                'main': 'main'

            },
            shim    :
            {
                'main':{
                    deps: ["angular", 'ngRoute']
                },
                'ngRoute':{
                    deps: ["angular"]
                }
            }
        });

 require( [ "main" ], function( app )
        {
            // Application has bootstrapped and started...
        });
```

`main.js` file

```
define([
    'common/RouteManager'
    ], function(RouteManager){
    var appName = 'elara',
        depends = ['ngRoute'],
        app = angular.module(appName, depends).config(RouteManager)

        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], [ ]);

        return app;
});
```

RouterManager.js

```
(function ( define ) {
    define([
        'controllers/account'
        ], function(){
        var RouteManager = $routeProvider.when("/", angularAMD.route({
            templateUrl: '/html/tmpl/test.html', controller: 'registerController',
            controllerUrl: 'controllers/account.js'
        })).otherwise({redirectTo: "/"});

        return ["$routeProvider", RouteManager ];
    })
});
```

And finally my controller:

```
define(['common/settings'], function(settings){
    var accountController = function($scope, $http){
        $scope.username = "";
        $scope.password = "";

        $scope.register = function(){
            $http.post(config.apiAddress + "account/login/", {username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}).then(
                function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }, function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                })
        }
    };

    return accountController;
});
```

I'm getting

> Argument 'accountController' is not a function, got undefined

exception. When i check network tab, my `account.js` file is not loaded. So angular don't know anything about `accountController`

Comment: Not to be that guy... but why use requireJS with Angular? For 99% of all Angular apps out there require would do nothing but add complexity. The savings you get from lazy-downloading files is nothing compared to the time invested (and you might even lose performance due to latency). Unless you are working on a truly huge codebase that is and lazy-downloading is a must.

Answer (score 0):

## Brackets

You are returning a function in your controller so it should be

```
return accountController();
```

**Not**

```
return accountController;
```

Comment: Added brackets but didn't make any difference. Thanks anyway :)